# Scraping milions of records with requests and lxml takes too long

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm writing simple scraper with requests and lxml.

Code works fine but scraping milions of records takes more than 10 days. Is it possible to make it faster using these two modules or is it only possible with async framework like scrapy?

Here's the full code:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

profile = 10100 #start from this profile
i = 0
while i<1000000:
    url = ("https://www.example.com/profile/10100")
    headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    doc = html.fromstring(r.content)
    mod = doc.xpath("//*[@id = 'achievement104' and @class='achievement ']/text()")
    name = doc.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/h1/text()")
    if len(mod) != 0: #if match
        print("Moderator!", name)
    else:
        print("Not moderator!", name)
    profile += 1 #go to another profile
    i += 1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I try your code, and then list the attributes you have:

```
import requests
url = ("https://www.example.com/profile/10100")
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
dir(r)
```

['**attrs**',
 '**bool**',
 '**class**',
 '**delattr**',
 '**dict**',
 '**dir**',
 '**doc**',
 '**enter**',
 '**eq**',
 '**exit**',
 '**format**',
 '**ge**',
 '**getattribute**',
 '**getstate**',
 '**gt**',
 '**hash**',
 '**init**',
 '**iter**',
 '**le**',
 '**lt**',
 '**module**',
 '**ne**',
 '**new**',
 '**nonzero**',
 '**reduce**',
 '**reduce_ex**',
 '**repr**',
 '**setattr**',
 '**setstate**',
 '**sizeof**',
 '**str**',
 '**subclasshook**',
 '**weakref**',
 '_content',
 '_content_consumed',
 '_next',
 'apparent_encoding',
 'close',
 'connection',
 'content',
 'cookies',
 'elapsed',
 'encoding',
 'headers',
 'history',
 'is_permanent_redirect',
 'is_redirect',
 'iter_content',
 'iter_lines',
 'json',
 'links',
 'next',
 'ok',
 'raise_for_status',
 'raw',
 'reason',
 'request',
 'status_code',
 'text',
 'url']

I don't see html, that's why you get an attr error.

Now the important part, if you check r.status_code (the response status code)

```
In [107]: r.status_code
Out[107]: 404
```

Which is a not found error, basically your specified url does NOT exist, or at least it is not visible for me.

Comment: Thank you for your reply E.Serra, it seems that my problem lays in chosen module. I used requests but worked with commands from module called requests-html :D

Comment: happy to help, good to know it worked. BTW requests is an awesome module

Comment: Yes, requests looks really great :) Anyway I rewrote my script and now it's "working". There's only one problem, script is too slow :( Is there any way of making it faster? Now it's scraping 1 profile per second. When I want to scrape milions of records it tooks forever. :X

Comment: Hey, can you please answer me? :)

Comment: well you will have to at least tell me how does example.com look like, but the usual bottleneck is the http request, which means you have 1 profile, query, wait for the server to receive the query, the server processes response, you wait for it then run the next one.
Most servers will have a way of returning a query that is a list, so you could batch your requests with something like https://www.example.com/profile/10100,10101,10102 (in some way to pass a list to the server so that it processes one petition and replies with multiple answers). As to how your server does that I have no clue

Comment: Also you can run multiple queries at the same time (this would be ajax in javascript, you fire all your queries and then wait for them to come back) as to how asynchronous requests are made in python, I have no idea, google it and try it, but the important part is passing the server a list I would say more than asynchronicity

Comment: thank you for your reply! I edited my question so if you want to try it just replace example.com with sololearn.com. Now I will try to rewrite it a little.

Comment: Unfortunately sololearn does not seem to have an API https://www.sololearn.com/Discuss/551126/solved-has-sololearn-api  an API is the kind of technology that allows you to do those queries (like asking for a list of users). they have purposefully not set it up public, which means you should not do this.
If you still want to do that, you can either wait a long time with a single process (which you don't want to), divide your for loop into different scripts (say 10 scripts each doing 1/10 of the requests) or set up something asynchhronous, but you will probably end up banned so be careful

Answer (score 1):

You should do that with the libxml

```
from lxml import html
import requests
url = ("https://www.example.com/profile/10100")
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"}
r = request.get(url, headers=headers)
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
```

and then you can use xpath in tree variable

Comment: Thank you asa, lxml looks great.